# Cannot run sidekiq on vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, vagrant, sidekiq

I am developing a web application by Ruby on Rails, and I want to send emails with `deliver_later`.

In `Gemfile`, `gem sidekiq`, and in `config/initializer/sidekiq.rb`,

```
redis_sec = { host: '127.0.0.1' }
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{redis_sec[:host]}:6379", namespace: 'sidekiq' }
end
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{redis_sec[:host]}:6379", namespace: 'sidekiq' }
end
```

finally, in `config/sidekiq.yml`,

```
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
```

I wrote a test sidekiq queue in `app/workers/worker_for_sidekiq.rb`:

```
class WorkerForSidekiq
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :sidekiq
  def perform(text)
    sleep 5
    p text
  end
end
```

Then, running sidekiq by `bundle exec sidekiq -q sidekiq` on vagrant gives an error:

```
ERR Syntax error, try CLIENT (LIST | KILL ip:port)
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:121:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis.rb:69:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:104:in `block in connect'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_reconnect'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:100:in `connect'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis.rb:105:in `connect'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:364:in `ensure_connected'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `block in process'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:306:in `logging'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:220:in `process'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:120:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis.rb:69:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:251:in `block in info'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in `block in synchronize'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in `synchronize'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:250:in `info'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.3/lib/sidekiq.rb:111:in `block in redis_info'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.3/lib/sidekiq.rb:95:in `block in redis'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in with'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:63:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:63:in `block in with'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:60:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:60:in `with'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.3/lib/sidekiq.rb:92:in `redis'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.3/lib/sidekiq.rb:106:in `redis_info'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.3/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:81:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.3/bin/sidekiq:12:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:335:in `exec'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:24:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

So, I try `reids-cli` and `CLIENT LIST`:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> CLIENT LIST
addr=127.0.0.1:49802 fd=5 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=client
```

I perfectly followed instructions of [this Japanese blog](http://jetglass.hatenablog.jp/entry/2015/07/15/181145). I googled some keywords such as 'sidekiq syntax error,' 'sidekiq vagrant error,' 'sidekiq virtualbox,' and 'sidekiq client list,' but no helpful articles are found.

What is wrong? Is sidekiq unavailable on vagrant?

---

- macOS Sierra 10.12.5
- vagrant 1.9.4
- centos64 (vagrant)
- ruby 2.3.0p0
- Rails 5.1.1
- Bundler 1.14.6

Gemfile:

```
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'redis', '3.3.3'
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'redis-namespace'
```

Comment: Which Redis version are you using? `redis-server --version`

Comment: Redis version is 2.4.10 (00000000:0).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stack trace, the error seems to originate from [this block](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/3.3/lib/redis/client.rb#L100):

```
with_reconnect(false) do
  establish_connection
  call [:auth, password] if password
  call [:select, db] if db != 0
  call [:client, :setname, @options[:id]] if @options[:id]
  @connector.check(self)
end
```

Note especially this line:

```
call [:client, :setname, @options[:id]] if @options[:id]
```

The `CLIENT SETNAME` command is only available from Redis 2.6.9. If you try to run it with an older version, you get the error message that you are seeing.

The solution to this is to upgrade Redis to at least 2.6.9.